# XAMPP Apache config test fail error: "symbol not found on modperl.."

Tags: apache, xampp, mod-perl

I installed XAMPP 7.2.7 version but Apache keeps on failing with this error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 522 of
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 13
> of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf:
>
> Cannot load modules/mod_perl.so into server:
> dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/mod_perl.so, 10): Symbol
> not found: _modperl_handler_anon_add
>
> Referenced from: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/mod_perl.so
>
> Expected in: dynamic lookup

I tried looking at the `httpd.conf`, `httpd-xampp.conf` files and tried to modify those lines hoping that it will fix the errors but it didn't. So it seems like the problem is with the `mod_perl.so` file but I can't open the file.

I re-installed `XAMPP` several times and downgraded to `7.1.x` but the same error occurred.

Forgot to mention this: I'm using macbook pro high sierra 10.13.5

Comment: Did you restart Apache after modifying the appropriate lines?

Comment: @ialarmedalien Apache never 'started' because of the error mentioned above

Comment: Are you using the standard installer from the XAMPP site? Have you had XAMPP working on your machine before, and do you have the Apache config files from that installation?

Comment: @ialarmedalien Yes i downloaded from the XAMPP site. Never used XAMPP before, this is first time installing. Forgot to mention this in the question, it's running on a macbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't say what you did to modify the lines but I just had this issue and commented out line 13 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf and it's working fin after a restart - obviously this means that you aren't loading the Pearl module but may work as an interim until you can find out what's wrong with that

Comment: thank! commenting lines did the trick :) Although it's not the real solution, it helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

To run Apache config test after modifying .conf files, and you are running XAMPP and its installed in the default /opt/lampp locaiton, then do the following, which should pinpoint the problem line.

#how to run Apache config test/check on xampp

```
/opt/lampp/bin/apachectl configtest
```

Or

```
/opt/lampp/bin/apachectl -t
```

Note, i see the OP has error and line reporting, but i posted above for anyone trying to run Apache configtest on xampp install which i didn't see in googling.